# bash expand variable in a variable, with $ as prefix

Tags: bash, function, variables, loops, expand

I am working on a bash function, and I suspect that it currently has a syntax error, the code is this:

```
for (( i=1; i<$#; i++))
do
  GET_BLOCK "/$${!i}/" ...
done
```

What I am trying to do is to run GET_BLOCK "/$1/" for the first parameter, "/$2/" for the second, and so on until there are no more parameters passed to the script. Am I doing this
right? (PS! I need to get the value of the variables $1, $2 exc...)

Comment: You don't need to put `SOLVED` in the question title; accepting an answer marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more idiomatic way of iterating over the positional parameters is to use `$@`:

```
for p in "$@"; do
    GET_BLOCK "/$p/"
done
```

What you wanted was

```
for ((i=1; i<$#; i++))
do
    GET_BLOCK "/${!i}"
done
```

but this is both non-standard and less clear than iterating over `$@` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! You are quite right, the problem though is that I need to take in an unknown amount of parameters. The first solution would only work for one parameter right?

Comment: No, `$@` expands to the list of all positional parameters, and when quoted, each parameter is individually quoted, so with a call like `script "foo bar" "1 2"`, `p` gets assigned first to `foo bar` and secondly to `1 2`.